# How often are Senators called on for violating Senate rules?

Tags: united-states, senate, legislative-process

As [widely reported now](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/07/us/politics/republican-senators-vote-to-formally-silence-elizabeth-warren.html?_r=0), Senator Elizabeth Warren was silenced by a vote in the Senate for purportedly violating Rule XIX.

In the last 10 years how many times (or approximately how many), have Senators been called on for violating Senate rules? Is a vote conducted every time?

Comment: Do you get a ticket every time you exceed the speed limit when driving?

Comment: @KDog Most of the time? Lol.

Comment: As a protest, multiple other Senators quoted the same passage as Warren but no vote was called and they weren't silenced.  I'd post that as an answer to your second question, but it doesn't address the spirit of the first.  Maybe change to "how often are Senators called on violating...".

Comment: @Brythan Sure, I'll update the question. That was also my motive for asking this question.

Comment: Please clarify whether *"how often"* is a rate question, (i.e. *x* times per duration *n*), or a historical question, (i.e. *y* times since the founding of the republic; *w* times in the last 30 years; etc.).

Comment: @agc I'm generally looking for past examples, maybe in the last 10 years or so.

Comment: Senate should keep disciplinary records somewhere, perhaps at senate.gov -- has anyone poked around there?

Comment: The only time people get called out for breaking the rules is when the press makes it a point. Or a membership of the Senate leadership decides they can make political points by doing so.

Comment: Are you looking for definitive often such as how often Halley's comet is visible from  Earth or is something less precise sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Senate historians, there are no formal records. One such [historian](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2017/feb/08/did-elizabeth-warren-break-rules-plus-5-other-ques/) claimed that since the rules inception in 1902, he is aware of two such instances. The last time dating back to the fifties. However, there is evidence of it happening [much later](http://www.cleveland.com/politics/index.ssf/2017/02/arcane_senate_rule_used_to_sil.html).

An important issue can be seen in that second article. Some things can be stricken from the official record. So between not officially recording instances of rule XIX, and the ability to alter the record, we cannot know for certain how many times it has been used, or how many times it may have been threatened but not used because the senator followed the rules once warned.